# Using a variable as part of an object?

Tags: javascript, html

Say you have the variable, *the reason I ask if it is possible to use a variable is if I were to use an input to dynamically change the var*:

```
var str = "pineapples"
var cost = {
pineapples: "free",
apples: "£1"
}
```

how would it be possible to use it as an object name

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=cost.??
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in js if variable is objects property name then [] brackets should be used

```
cost[str]
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple, add the string to the object:

```
cost[ str ] = inputString;
```

than retrieve it after:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cost.str;
```

Comment: Using `cost.str` will attempt to find a property literally called `str` in the `cost` object.

Comment: I am confused. what is the OP looking for than?

Comment: The OP doesn't appear to know about bracket notation on objects, so that is what s/he is looking for. Your answer would be correct if you retrieved the value via `cost[str]` (looks for a property whose name is the *value* of `str`) rather than via `cost.str` (looks for a property whose name is literally `str`).